# What is the best practice to import css Bootstrap into Bitrix24 framework?

Tags: bitrix

In the Bitrix Framework, I want to embed Css BootStrap into. Anyways, I don't know where is the best practice to add directory of Bootstrap library. Please kindly help to guide me if you have experience on bitrix development. Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can add any css/js files with this code (ex. at header.php)

`\Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset::getInstance()->addCss($relativePathToCssFile);`
`\Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset::getInstance()->addJs($relativePathToJsFile);`

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/main/page/asset/addcss.php

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/main/page/asset/addjs.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I just want to know where can add bootrap library into project. What is the best practice to do that?

Comment: @KOCHDOEUN I would add those files to template dir under css/js.